# How do I make a JList automatically stretch with the window in a netbeans Swing app?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlist

I have a simple java swing app, built in netbeans. There's a JList in the app (inside a JScrollPane -- netbeans automatically creates this). I want the JList to grow and shrink when the user resizes the main window.

What do I have to do in netbeans to tie the horizontal and vertical size of the JList to the main window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) use proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), if I understood correctly [BorderLayout.CENTER](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) can do that

2) put [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) to the [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

3) write code by your hands and edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrated your issue(s)

Comment: #2 -- I edited the question, it already has a JScrollPane. #3 -- yes, I could hand code it, but the crux of the question is "how do you do it in netbeans?".

Comment: same way in the Netbeans as in Eclipse, TextPad or Notepad, have to waiting for your edit :-)

Comment: (I'm Netbeans user too) don't use code generated by Netbeans, you have to accepting the disclaimer, unfortunatelly this Frameworks was stopped somewhere betweens 1st. quater and half of development

Comment: +1 agree. The GUI editor is like a power saw—it makes the work go faster, but it can't tell you what wood to use or where to cut.

Comment: @trashgod "..or where to cut.." ..or to keep your fingers clear of the spinning blades or..

Answer (score 3):

In the GUI editor add a JPanel, set the layout to Free Design. Then you can attach the JList to all siding components (with margin) so the JList is resized.

Comment: Have you an idea whats wrong here?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpqhD.gif

Comment: I did not see a selection of the lower part, where it should be possible to _connect_ below to selected panel. A BorderPane would do it automatically.

Comment: No idea what you mean.

Comment: 'Tschuldigung. Your problem I think: the panel and the bottom part do not connect to each other. Resizing all will make a gap. For that problem ideally the container best is a BorderPane, with your panel at the center and the footer at the bottom.

Comment: I am just now programming in JavaFX, BorderLayout of course. Sorry my head.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me in netbeans. Ill open ticket.